# AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to make a liking system with `LikeView` and `BlogDetails` such as if I like it and then click again I disliked it

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    Post.likes.remove(id=request.user)
    liked = False
else:
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    liked = True
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog-detail', args=[str(pk)]))




class BlogDetails(DetailView):
model = Post
template_name = 'blog_details.html'
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = super(BlogDetails, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['categories'] = categories
    liked = False
    stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
    context['likes'] = total_likes
    if stuff.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
        Liked = True
    context['liked'] = liked
    return context
```

and it shows an AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: Use lowercase p in this line `Post.likes.remove(id=request.user.id)`

Comment: Can you share your full `traceback` ?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like :-

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(id=request.user) # Changed Here
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog-detail', args=[str(pk)]))
```